# What is the best approach to write a lot of many to many relationships?

Tags: database-design

I have a lot of models that creates many to many relationship i.e. Business, Agency, Space, Report, Campaign.

```
1. Campaign hasMany Agencies and Agency hasMany Campaigns
2. A Business hasMany campaigns but a Campaign belongToOne Agency
3. Agency hasMany Spaces 
4. A Report has many spaces, hasMany Campaigns, hasMany Agencies and One Business
```

Now there are multiple options to design the schema. I am thinking the below generic polymorphic relationship but do not know the costs:

`attachable_id, attachable_type attached_with_id, attached_with_type`

The other option is to make tables like:

```
space_id, spacable_id, spacable_type  (polymorphic relationship with space and space attachables)
```

I want to know the different kind of costs in terms of DB Design..

Comment: I suspect there's a typo in item 2 - otherwise, it contradicts item 1.

Comment: I know generic solutions sounds nice but usually they don't play well with table stats. Optimizer might have problems deciding optimal plan as a consequence. In the long run it might prove to be more costly to maintain such generic solutions than it would be to maintain a standard many to many model. Consider a situation where you would want to add an attribute to a **single** relationship. In a generic solution you would add an attribute to **all** relations.